# "Cannot find a differ supporting object" error while trying to apply styles from database

Tags: angular, primeng

I've got a dynamic table and I want to update the styles on the fly using database queries. I've got a Java backend that's populating a list of column objects on the frontend but none of the styles from my database are being applied. I keep getting the error that a differ supporting object cannot be found, even though I'm parsing the string as a JSON object. Is there something I'm missing?

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<th *ngFor="let column of columns"
     pReorderableColumn
    [pReorderableColumnDisabled]="!hasReorderableColumns"
    [pSortableColumn]="column?.sortKey || column?.field"
    [pSortableColumnDisabled]="!isSortable || column?.sortable === 0"
    [ngStyle]="style(column)">
  {{ column?.header }}
  <p-sortIcon *ngIf="isSortable && column?.sortable !== 0" [field]="column?.sortKey || column?.field"></p-sortIcon>
</th>
```

And this is the style function in my component:

```
style(column: Column) {
  return column.styles ? JSON.parse(<string>column.styles) : null;
}
```

And this is the column object:

```
export class Column {
  header: string;
  field: string;
  dataType?: string;
  sortKey?: string;
  styles?: Object;
  templateName?: string;
  filterMatchMode?: string;
  defaultSort?: SortOrder;
  isFilterable?: number;
  sortable?: number;
  filter?: any;
  isDefault?: number;
  dataTableId?: number;
  dataTableColumnId?: number;
  resource?: string;
  isCacheable?: boolean;
  label?: string;
  value?: string;
  createdBy?: number;
  createdDate?: string;
  modifiedBy?: number;
  modifiedDate?: string;
}
```

Styles is an object because in other parts of the codebase I'm just passing in a JSON object directly instead of populating it with a string from the database.

I've tried a few different ways to parse the column style, but nothing's worked. The JSON string I'm feeding it is just '{"width":"10px"}'.

Comment: Can you check what `columns` contains and make sure it's an array?